# Reconfiguring UICollectionView cell data within a UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Say I have a `collectionView`, using a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Section, Row>` where `Section` is

```swift
enum Section {
    case info
}
```

and `Row` is

```swift
enum Row {
    case name(name: String)
    case description(description: String)
}
```

I then define a configuration for these cells

```swift
let textRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<TextInputCollectionViewCell, Row> { (cell, indexPath, item) in
    cell.item = item
}
```

I have a delegate method setup to be notified when the content of these cells change from user input,

```swift
func nameDidChange(to newName: String?) {
    self.navigationItem.title = newTitle
    //Update my model
}

func descriptionDidChange(to newDescription: String?) {
    //Update my model
}
```

Now here is my issue, if I initially add this data to my `dataSource` like this:

```swift
var infoSnapshot = self.dataSource.snapshot()
        
infoSnapshot.appendSections([.info])
infoSnapshot.appendItems([
    .name(name: self.myModel.name),
    .description(description: self.myModel.description)
], toSection: .info)

self.dataSource.apply(infoSnapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
```

As soon as this cell is offscreen and reset, once it comes back it uses the old data initially set in the method above.

How do I reset the data, if doing so would change the hash, messing with my diffable datasource? Should I set the data elsewhere, not tying it to the dataSource?

| Before Editing | During Editing | After Editing |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] | [image] |

Comment: It seems like you're appending a new item to the datasource but not removing the old one.

Comment: Well I don't necessarily *want* to remove the old, as the cell is the name. I want to update the data, but not sure how to do that here